# React Packager 0.44.0

Tags: react-native

First of all I am new to react native platform and I am developing an app but I am facing one issue when I run my application after changes made in classes.
I am posting my logs below, Thank you for your help folks....

**index.android.js (loads successfully but app do not run)**

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)

{ 
  Error: write EPIPE
    at _errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
    at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:767:25)
    at Socket._write (net.js:786:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:387:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:373:5)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:290:11)
    at Socket.write (net.js:704:40)
    at Socket.Writable.end (_stream_writable.js:553:10)
    at Socket.end (net.js:496:31)
    at Promise.resolve.then.then.then.catch.then.message 

    (E:\FinalDownload\takeawaymobileapp\node_modules\react-native\packager\src\Server\symbolicate\worker.js
:35:33) code: 'EPIPE', errno: 'EPIPE', syscall: 'write' }
```

Comment: Please add [mcve] to your question.

Comment: Can you post the code that it breaks on?